# Validar una palabra completa con regex

Tags: python, regex

Estoy tratando de usar regex para validar que una palabra se encuentre dentro de dos signos iguales en este caso `%` y la palabra puede contener cualquier carácter especial. Para este ejemplo una palabra válida sería por ejemplo: `%Palabra_valida%`

Este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
import re

regex =re.compile(r'[%a-z_A-Z%]')

palabras = ["%hola%","sdsd","%gff"]
for i in palabras:
    r = regex.match(i)
    if r :
        print(r)
```

pero no valida la palabra completa únicamente valida que un caracter este dentro de los dos signos iguales `%`
¿Qué está fallando?

Comment: Me parece que la socluon es: `re.compile(r'%[\w]*%')` podrian corroborar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es exactamente lo que buscas pero puedes probar con la regex `%\w+%` el símbolo + indica que debe de haber 1 o más apariciones, por lo que reconocerá tantas letras como haya entre los símbolos %